# How to transpose table SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I`m trying to transpose table, but I get message that type of column conflicts with other.
This is solution

```
WITH CTE_Unpivoted as
( select ID, Fields, QuantityValue
from Bikes2 as s
UNPIVOT
(QuantityValue for Fields IN(ProductName, Country, Quantity)
)AS u
)
SELECT Fields, [1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7]
from CTE_Unpivoted AS u
PIVOT
(SUM(QuantityValue) for ID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])) AS p
```

This is data

```
CREATE TABLE Bikes2
 (ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
 ProductName VARCHAR(50),
 Country VARCHAR(50),
 Quantity INT);
INSERT INTO Bikes2 VALUES ('Road Bike', 'USA', 128)
INSERT INTO Bikes2 VALUES ('Road Bike', 'Italy', 64)
INSERT INTO Bikes2 VALUES ('Electric Bike', 'USA', 257)
INSERT INTO Bikes2 VALUES ('Electric Bike', 'Italy', 143)
INSERT INTO Bikes2 VALUES ('Children Bicecle', 'USA', 386)
INSERT INTO Bikes2 VALUES ('Children Bicecle', 'Italy', 52)
INSERT INTO Bikes2 VALUES ('Road Bike', 'USA', 35)
SELECT * FROM Bikes2
```

How to do this right? Is it possible make it dynamic?
And result smt like this

[image: table]

Comment: Please show us the result that you want for this sample data.

Comment: Obviously, you should convert all the columns to the same datatype. Looks like to `varchar`, as it is the most generic and other columns can be converted to it. Or how do you want to store numbers, dates and strings in the same column, when in SQL result column should have a single type?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64909988/edit) to include this information.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in SQL? Changing things like the quantity to a `varchar` is going to be problematic down the road if you want to do "simple" things like `SUM` it (which is exactly what you then try to do in the `PIVOT`).

Comment: Added result in the end. When I try to convert Quantity to varchar(50) I still get an error

Comment: Yes, you'll get the error I mention above, @OlhaTkachuk, that `varchar` isn't a valid datatype for a `SUM`.

Comment: Is it possible at all doint this through UNPIVOT/PIVOT if datatype isn`t valid and I can't convert it?

Comment: Having a look at the picture for expected result, you're not looking for grouped sums for `product_name` and `country` columns, but keep the number of rows inserted to the table `Bikes2` in order to pivot, but why there are missing values for 6th and 7th columns in the result? OR indeed you need grouped summation for those columns. eg. should there exist numbered columns upto 6, rather than 7 in the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of reformatting is better done in the application layer rather than in the database.  Here are two reasons why:

- A SQL query returns a fixed number of columns, and you seem to want one column per row in the table.  So you have to hardwire that number.
- Each column has a single type, but your data has strings and numbers.

That said, it is possible.  Here is one method:

```
with b as (
      select b.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from bikes2 b
     )
select 'productname',
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then productname end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then productname end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then productname end),
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then productname end),
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then productname end),
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then productname end),
       max(case when seqnum = 7 then productname end)
from b
union all
select 'country',
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then country end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then country end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then country end),
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then country end),
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then country end),
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then country end),
       max(case when seqnum = 7 then country end)
from b
union all
select 'quantity',
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then cast(quantity as varchar(255)) end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then cast(quantity as varchar(255)) end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then cast(quantity as varchar(255)) end),
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then cast(quantity as varchar(255)) end),
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then cast(quantity as varchar(255)) end),
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then cast(quantity as varchar(255)) end),
       max(case when seqnum = 7 then cast(quantity as varchar(255)) end)
from b;
```

This can be shorted to:

```
with b as (
      select b.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from bikes2 b
     )
select name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end),
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then val end),
       max(case when seqnum = 5 then val end),
       max(case when seqnum = 6 then val end),
       max(case when seqnum = 7 then val end)
from b cross apply
     (values (1, 'productname', productname),
             (2, 'country', country),
             (3, 'quantity', convert(varchar(255), quantity))
     ) v(ord, name, val)
group by name, ord
order by ord;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=723cc6e2c9c3eaa4fdf7b79db9018ed7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: So basically speaking I can`t do this through UNPIVOT/PIVOT? Diffrent Datatypes prevents this?

Comment: @OlhaTkachuk . . . You probably could.  However, that is bespoke, non-standard syntax.  Lateral joins are standard syntax and more powerful.  So, I recommend using explicit lateral joins.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer really did help me